# Convert date and time from two columns into a single datetime column using Dask map_partitions

Tags: date, datetime, type-conversion, dask, dask-dataframe

How can I convert two date and time columns of this type:

```
Date    Time
1/01/1990   1055
2/01/1990   1055
3/01/1990   1055
4/01/1990   1729
5/01/1990   1729
```

into a single datetime column (e.g format='%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d') using dask map_partitions ?

Answer (score 0):

I would figure out how to do this with Pandas, and then use the map_partitions function on a dask dataframe to apply that function in parallel.

The Pandas tag on Stack Overflow is also very well maintained, so asking a question there is likely to get a fast response.